# LoadLibrary at run time gets errorcode 126 when using external dynamic library

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, visual-studio-2019, dllimport

So I have a sample code (everything in c++) that I was able to compile into dll using visual studio 2019 (everything is compiled in 64bit). I have a test code that loads the compiled dll during runtime. However, as soon as I refer to another library(opencv in this case), I would get an error on the load module (126, I assume it means it couldn't find the dll file or something).

Things I've tried so far:

1. Adding library path and include path and all the dlls from opencv to
           my dll doesn't cause any error. but as soon as I add "#include
           "opencv2/opencv.hpp" " I get 126 (the dll still builds fine).
2. I added the same dynamic linkage to the load module (already static
   linked to the same library), still no dice.

**Update**: After checking with process monitor I found out the OpenCV module cannot be found, which is quite bizarre as I have specified the locations under Additional library directory and include directory (I used the one under vcpkg/installed). The process monitor shows that of all the places the load module was looking for the opencv dll, only the vcpkg location was not looked at.

[image: process monitor output]

**update2:**
I took out all the linker to the opencv dll and the issue didn't show up on the process monitor, however, I'm still getting the code 126 .

**update3:**
Did a quick file search, didn't even have the dll files to begin with. Downloaded the required dll and left them in the root folder of my load module, problem solved. I want my three hours back.

Comment: That's `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`. Which means that a dependent module cannot be found. Use loader snaps to work out which one it is.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I just used process monitor to check which ones are not loaded, looks like windows is looking for opencv dll under a completely different folder.  This is weird as I have specified where the dll for the opencv module would be. Is there anything I might be missing here?

Comment: Nothing you do in the VS options has any bearing on where the system looks for DLLs. You need to read about the DLL search order. Websearch will get you there.

Comment: Right, but do I need to link dll to the load module as well (its already statically linked to the same OpenCV library)? because it seems that when loading my own compiled dll the load module should automatically search for the dependent dlls to my own compiled dlls.

Comment: Sorry, just checked again and apparently the dll side when trying to load the module specified still failed to find the right one under vcpkg folder, ill look into that rn.

Answer (score -1):

Did a quick file search, didn't even have the dll files to begin with. Downloaded the required dll and left them in the root folder of my load module, problem solved. I want my three hours back.